# How to hide a :after link for mobile layout Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, pseudo-element

I have created a navigation row that includes image sprites.  I would also like it to have a short text description on the right of each icon (eg Home, Services, etc), but need the text hidden for mobile layout and this is where I am getting stuck:

Stylesheet is as follows:

```
.lnx { position: relative; display: table-row; padding: 0; margin: 8px 0; }
.lnx li, .lnx a { height: 54px; display: table-cell !important; }
.lnx li.spritehom { left: 0; min-width: 50px !important; display: table-cell; background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0 0; }
.lnx li.spritehom:hover, .lnx li.active.spritehom { background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0px -54px; }

.spritehom:after { content: "home"; clear: left; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle;height: 54px; }
.spriteabt:after { /*content: "about"; */
                clear: left; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle; height: 54px; }
.spritesvs:after { /*content: "services"; */
                clear: left; margin: 0 15%; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle; height: 54px; }
.spritepor:after { /*content: "portfolio"; */
                clear: left; margin: 0 15%; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle; height: 54px; }
.spritecon:after { /*content: "contact"; */
                clear: left; margin: 0 15%; display: table-cell !important; vertical-align: middle; height: 54px; }

.lnx li.spriteabt { left: 0; min-width: 50px !important; display: table-cell; 
 background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0 -108px; }
.lnx li.spriteabt:hover, .lnx li.active.spriteabt  {
background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0px -162px; }
.lnx li.spritesvs { left: 0; min-width: 50px !important; display: table-cell; 
 background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0 -216px; }
.lnx li.spritesvs:hover, .lnx li.active.spritesvs  {
background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0px -270px; } 
.lnx li.spritepor { left: 0; min-width: 50px !important; display: table-cell; 
background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0 -324px; }
.lnx li.spritepor:hover, .lnx li.active.spritepor  {
background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0px -378px; }    
.lnx li.spritecon { left: 0; min-width: 50px !important; display: table-cell; 
 background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0 -432px; }
.lnx li.spritecon:hover, .lnx li.active.spritecon  {
background: url('../images/btnsprite.png') no-repeat 0px -486px; }
```

Page layout is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/lfstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/lfstyle.less rel="stylesheet/less">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via  -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row blk">&nbsp</div>
<div class="row blu">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 log"><a href="/"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
<div class="col-md-8 slog"><h2>Slogan</h2>
<p class="cal"><span="ti">T:</span> 01234 567890    <span class="ti">E:</span> me@you.com</p></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 lnx">
             <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                   <li class="spritehom"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="spriteabt"><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li class="spritesvs"><a href="#"></a></li>
                   <li class="spritepor"><a href="#"></a></li>
                  <li class="spritecon"><a href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please could anyone advise how I can hide the :after links for mobile layout?  I am very comfortable with CSS and HTML.  Not as much so with less, but I am always willing to learn.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text in a `span` with class `hidden-xs`, and it will only show on sm, md and lg.

```
<li class="spritehom"><a href="#"><span class="hidden-xs"> Text</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn, with a bit of styling, that option worked.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this, but the the links on the icons aren't working when viewed on phone.  On desktop the icons and the links work.  Is there a workaround?